# What's Wrong with My Python Script?

Tags: python

I'm trying to learn more about using the info window with Python. Turning it into an addon. I feel like I got pretty close, but it is giving me an error.

```
import bpy

class cubeMover():

    bpy.ops.transform.translate(value=(0, 2.86946, 0), orient_type='GLOBAL', orient_matrix=((1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 1)), orient_matrix_type='GLOBAL', constraint_axis=(False, True, False), mirror=True, proportional='DISABLED', proportional_edit_falloff='SMOOTH', proportional_size=1, release_confirm=True)


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(cubeMover)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(cubeMover)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

When I run the code using just this it runs fine.

```
import bpy
bpy.ops.transform.translate(value=(0, 2.86946, 0), orient_type='GLOBAL', orient_matrix=((1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 1)), orient_matrix_type='GLOBAL', constraint_axis=(False, True, False), mirror=True, proportional='DISABLED', proportional_edit_falloff='SMOOTH', proportional_size=1, release_confirm=True)
```

But when I try and change it into an addon it doesn't work.

Comment: _"I feel like I got pretty close"_ In reality you are a long way from close.  See https://docs.blender.org/api/blender2.8/info_quickstart.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably define an operator. See Python example files that come with Blender about how to write an operator:

[image]

It might be a good idea to change objects location directly instead of using an operator that is for user interaction. You can change the location of the active object by changing `bpy.context.object.location` values.

Comment: OK thanks. I'll keep that in mind. 
So let's say I use the "Operator Simple" default python code they give me.
What would the final code look like if I wanted to rotate the cube 60 degrees on the x axis?